# Best way to update an existing third party reference to that from NuGet

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I have been trying to use NuGet in a complex solution (with around 100 project files) and been struggling with updating the existing references (from a /ext/.. directory ) to that of official NuGet directory. As far as I understand we need to manually select the project files (from the PackagaManager GUI/Manage Assemblies) and update the references. This is cumbersome to know which project uses what out of 100 odd projects. Is there any way (built-in to nuget or any other workaround) to update assemblies to nuget directory without having to manually select projects?

Comment: Not sure I get it. 

If you installed a package to a project through NuGet Package Manager, it automatically adds library references, and keeps a reference to the package in packages.config inside the project's folder.

Then Update-Package will automatically search and update packages on a per project basis. You can also restrict to a project with -ProjectName

Also "get-package -ProjectName <myproject>" will return the list of packages installed in a given project.

Comment: Yeah that bit is sorta clear. The problem i have is, say i have a existing log4net reference that is coming from my own trunk\ext\lib\log4net library. And now i want to change this to trunk\packages\log4net\ by using NuGet. But the problem is I do not know for sure what project is currently having log4net, to update that only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not supported as yet and I've registered an [issue](https://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/2304) under codeplex's nuget project.